# Requesting multiple Entities by ID (keys) in OData

Tags: rest, api, odata

Does anyone know how to request multiple Entities by ID in OData?

There is a public OData feed on the internet that everyone can test:
just put the below URL in your browser and you can see the list of People: (or simply just click on the below link)

https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People

Now you can request the entity which its **russellwhyte** this way:
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People('russellwhyte')

same goes for another entity which its key is **javieralfred**
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People('javieralfred')

as you notice perhaps all of the URLs are Get (HTTP GET) as you are able to copy/paste them into the browser.

Now the question is:
what is the correct URL when I need to request an array of entities by their Keys?

Comment: DId you ever figure this out, I am curious as well?